# Handling the command elements together in the column break by multicols

Tags: multicol, chess, chessboard, columnbreak

I try to break the pages with chess diagrams containing the header to the two different columns. The problem is that the command elements are not process processed together. For example, in one of the pages, the header is in another page, while the diagram and notation in another:

[image: The page with the problem 1][image: The page with the problem 2]

Also, I provide the simplified code:

```
\documentclass[paper=7in:10in,DIV=calc,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=0.5in, outer=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{55}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{55}

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}

\newcounter{diagramsforinstruction}
\newcommand\printdiagramsforinstruction{\small\refstepcounter{diagramsforinstruction}\thediagramsforinstruction}

\newcommand\introductionboard[3][]{%
\setchessboard{showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, boardfontsize=20pt}
 \bgroup\medskip\par\large\bfseries #1
  \centering\par\makebox[1em][l]{\printdiagramsforinstruction}\chessboard[#2]\par\egroup\bgroup\centering\small #3\par\medskip\egroup\vfill\null\columnbreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\introductionboard[Timofeev vs Dimitrijevic 2004]{setfen=1r1qn1k1/1r1b1pb1/3pp1p1/3N2P1/p2NP3/5P2/1PP4Q/1KBR3R w}{Here, White managed to mate Black after \textbf{26. Qh7+ Kf8 27. Qh8+! Bxh8 28. Rxh8+ Kg7 29. Rdh1} and Black resigned due to the threat Rh1-h7\#.}
\introductionboard[Hlousek vs Novak, 1970, Solingen, match (6)]{setfen=3qb1k1/1n1r2pp/3p1p2/1pnPpN2/2p1P1P1/2P1B2P/QPB2P2/4R1K1 w}{Here, White managed to enter to the opponent's position after \textbf{28. Ra1 Rc7 29. Qa8} (changing the defender) \textbf{29...Qxa8 30. Rxa8 Kf8 31. Nxg7!} The tactical shot. \textbf{31...Rxg7} (if 31...Kg7 then 32.Re8\WBetter) \textbf{32. Bh6\WBetter} \ Black resigned.}
\introductionboard[Timofeev vs Dimitrijevic 2004]{setfen=1r1qn1k1/1r1b1pb1/3pp1p1/3N2P1/p2NP3/5P2/1PP4Q/1KBR3R w}{Here, White managed to mate Black after \textbf{26. Qh7+ Kf8 27. Qh8+! Bxh8 28. Rxh8+ Kg7 29. Rdh1} and Black resigned due to the threat Rh1-h7\#.}
\introductionboard[Hlousek vs Novak, 1970, Solingen, match (6)]{setfen=3qb1k1/1n1r2pp/3p1p2/1pnPpN2/2p1P1P1/2P1B2P/QPB2P2/4R1K1 w}{Here, White managed to enter to the opponent's position after \textbf{28. Ra1 Rc7 29. Qa8} (changing the defender) \textbf{29...Qxa8 30. Rxa8 Kf8 31. Nxg7!} The tactical shot. \textbf{31...Rxg7} (if 31...Kg7 then 32.Re8\WBetter) \textbf{32. Bh6\WBetter} \ Black resigned.}
\introductionboard[Timofeev vs Dimitrijevic 2004]{setfen=1r1qn1k1/1r1b1pb1/3pp1p1/3N2P1/p2NP3/5P2/1PP4Q/1KBR3R w}{Here, White managed to mate Black after \textbf{26. Qh7+ Kf8 27. Qh8+! Bxh8 28. Rxh8+ Kg7 29. Rdh1} and Black resigned due to the threat Rh1-h7\#.}
\introductionboard[Hlousek vs Novak, 1970, Solingen, match (6)]{setfen=3qb1k1/1n1r2pp/3p1p2/1pnPpN2/2p1P1P1/2P1B2P/QPB2P2/4R1K1 w}{Here, White managed to enter to the opponent's position after \textbf{28. Ra1 Rc7 29. Qa8} (changing the defender) \textbf{29...Qxa8 30. Rxa8 Kf8 31. Nxg7!} The tactical shot. \textbf{31...Rxg7} (if 31...Kg7 then 32.Re8\WBetter) \textbf{32. Bh6\WBetter} \ Black resigned.}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The question is:

How should I change the code of **\introductionboard** so that all elements of the command are handled together and fit in an column?

Comment: What exa tly is the desired output? Probably you could use a different approach than multicols.

Comment: I thought if I can separate the positions within one page.

Answer (score 0):

The possible answer is to use \begin{minipage} for the \introductionboard command:

```
\newcommand\introductionboard[3][]{%
\begin{minipage}{0.44\textwidth}
\setchessboard{showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, boardfontsize=20pt}
 \bgroup\medskip\par\large\bfseries #1
  \centering\par\makebox[0.5em][l]{\printdiagramsforinstruction}\chessboard[#2]\par\egroup\bgroup\centering\small #3\par\medskip\egroup
  \vfill\null\columnbreak\end{minipage}}
```